# C# Merging dictionaries inside of an object

Tags: c#, dictionary, for-loop, merge, concatenation

I realize there are tons of posts on this subject but I still haven't found what I am looking for reading the answers.

I get two objects A and B, that both have a dictionary and a set of booleans. Dictionaries are shaped the same, just the data differs. My end goal here is to create a 3rd object C, copy of A with its dictionary updated to have values from A and B according to a set of rules (for instance C.dictionary would have all A.dictionary.[x] if A.Dictionary.[x].Value.days < 5 and and all B.dictionary.[x] if days > 5).
If you have a solution for this that would be awesome, otherwise, here is where I am at and where I fail:

I am trying to create a new dictionary and and loop through A and B to add the values... I'll add the rules after. Once I will have it I'll find a way to place this dictionary into object C. (tell me if over engineered, I am very new to C#).

```
var dict = new Dictionary<DateTime, TypeData>();
foreach (var item in A.dictionary.keys)
   {
      dict.Add(A.Dictionary[item]);
   }
```

This does not work for 2 reasons:

- item does represents A.dictionary[x].key not A.dictionary[x] (also contains value and non public members)
- "Add" gets underlines and does not show more info for the error

Thanks a lot for checking my post !

Comment: Your Add is wrong, since it's missing the key. You would need to do: dict.Add(item, A.Dictionary[item]). You probalby want some key checking to and rename the var item into key for readability

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.add?view=net-5.0) for the Add method.

Comment: Surely visual studio will tell you what problems it sees when underline something. Just hoover over it and it will tell you that your call to add will not fit to the known signature of that method. And it will show you the valid signature and that it needs 2 parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I was able to do it by looping through keyvaluepair and add both kvp.key and kvp.Value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var dictionariesToCombine = new Dictionary<DateTime, TypeData>[] {dictA,dictB};

Dictionary<int, int> dictC = new Dictionary<DateTime, TypeData>();

    for (var i=0; i< dictionariesToCombine.Length; i++)
    {
        foreach (var item in dictionariesToCombine[i])
        {
            if( 
                  (i==0 and your conditions)
                 || (i==1 and your conditions)
               )
            resultDict.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Serge, that works !!